# Plotly line annotations with multiple lines

Tags: r, plotly, data-visualization

**Problem:** Basically, I want to annotate the y-values for each line in the plot for `mpg` (first line) and `disp` (second line).

How can I extend the below toy example code to achieve this? 2x `add_text()` layer is not working ...

Many thanks!

```
plot_ly(mtcars, 
        x = ~wt) %>% 
  add_lines(y = ~mpg,
            text = ~mpg) %>%
  add_text() %>%
  add_lines(y = ~disp,
            text = ~disp) %>%
  add_text()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since each addition inherits from the original `plot_ly` call, you need to specify the `y` and `text` values for each call to `add_text`. To my knowledge, they won't inherit the `y` or `text` values from the preceding call to `add_lines`.

```r
plot_ly(mtcars, 
        x = ~wt) %>% 
  add_lines(y = ~mpg) %>%
  add_text(y = ~mpg,
           text = ~mpg) %>%
  add_lines(y = ~disp) %>%
  add_text(y = ~disp,
           text = ~disp)
```

[image]